# Hyperlink not shown in gmail with email composer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, gmail

I am trying to send html as a body with email composer. html body contains hyperlink but it is not working in gmail. Gmail display plain text only.

```
  var email = {
                          to: sendersemail+';',
                          cc: '',
                          bcc: '',
                          attachments: [cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+'Report.pdf'],
                          subject: '',
                          body: '<p><a href="https://thebrainout.com/" target="_blank">the brain out</a> &nbsp;your  I think you&#39;ll find it helpful&nbsp;too.</p>',
                          isHtml: true
                        };

                       $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
                         // user cancelled email
                       });
```

Answer (score 4):

use html instead of body!

```
 var email = {
                      to: sendersemail+';',
                      cc: '',
                      bcc: '',
                      attachments: [cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+'Report.pdf'],
                      subject: '',
                      html: '<p><a href="https://thebrainout.com/" target="_blank">the brain out</a> &nbsp;your  I think you&#39;ll find it helpful&nbsp;too.</p>'

                    };

                   $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
                     // user cancelled email
                   });
```

Comment: is html work? i have tried but its not working for me.